# Angular Dart - Send data to controller using router.go

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I want to send parameters to my Controller using the router.go redirection.

I tried this :

```
 this._router.go('game', {'data': 'myData'});
```

Is it possible to get the parameters like that :

```
GameController(this._scope, this._router){
  print(this._router.parameters['data']);
}
```

If I want to "print" that, it returns null.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into this myself. I don't know if its the way to do it, but it works:

In your routes, you have to add the parameter 'data' to 'game', something like:

```
..addRoute(name: "game", 
   path: "/game/:data", 
   enter: view("views/game.html"))
```

after this you are able to fetch the parameter with:

```
GameController(this._scope, this._router){
    print(this._router.parameters['data']);
}
```

Seems like you have to introduce all the parameters you want to use to Angulars Routes before.

BR